# How to reset the field style in jQuery-Form-Validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'd like to reset the style any element in [jQuery-Form-Validator](http://formvalidator.net/).

I've seen that the next following is used to do it:

```
$('#exportMapForm').get(0).reset();
```

But the only thing that has been removed is the data and not its style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Finally I could to solved it and the answer was writting by @ChristynCanada [Link to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171381/red-border-still-appears-on-inputs-after-resetting-an-html-5-form-firefox)

Basically, we need to add the following code:

```
// To register all properties the `form` before resetting
form('exportMapForm').registerReset();
// Reset
form('exportMapForm').Reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.reset()` function removes the data and does not alter the style. To access the style of a particular DOM node (which in your case, looks like `$('#exportMapForm')`) you can use something like

```
$('#exportMapForm').className = '.myResetStyleClass';
```

Also, since the hash/pound symbol is an ID selector, and there should only ever be one element with that particular ID, there is no need for `.get(0)` after `$('#exportMapForm')`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to put the original Bootstrap style there?